# Wordpress Error 404 Not Found con Permalink

Tags: wordpress

He movido un WordPress de un servidor a otro con CentOS. La página funciona bien, pero los enlaces permanentes no funcionan correctamente.
Pongo la configuracuón como "simpre" y funcionan correctamente, pero al poner la opcion "Nombre de la entrada" o "Estructura personalizada" deja de funcionar apareciendo un error de tipo 404 Not Found.

Los permisos de DocumentRoot son apache.apache y tienen acceso y permisos correctos para acceder. Añado la configuración que tengo hasta ahora:

El rewrite_module se carga:

```
[root@srvws01 conf.d]# apachectl -M | grep rewrite_module
 rewrite_module (shared)
```

Mi fichero de configuración Apache www.domain.es.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
  ServerName www.domain.es
  ServerAlias domain.es www.domain.es

  LogLevel debug
  KeepAliveTimeout 100

  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_www.domain.es_log
  CustomLog logs/access_www.domain.es_log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.domain.es

 <Directory "/var/www/html/www.domain.es">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

El contenido del fichero .htaccess (/var/www/html/www.domain.es/.htaccess):

```
# BEGIN WordPress

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

He recreado el archivo .htaccess y el problema persiste. ¿Qué puede pasar y qué puedo hacer?
Gracias

Comment: Cuando se editan los permalinks a veces no se actualiza bien la referencia de wordpress. En el `wp-admin` ves a `Settings > permalinks > Save Changes` simplemente entra ahi y guarda los cambios aunque no modifiques nada, se actualizan las referencias y a veces el problema es simplemente ese. Asegurate tambien que esté marcado el check de `post name` en esos mismos ajustes porque quizas se te haya cambiado a otro tipo

Comment: Lo tengo con el tag /%postname%/ y el fichero /var/www/html/www.domain.es/.htaccess actualizado (mediante el wp-admin) de ahora a las 15:01.
Sigue apareciendo el 404...

Comment: ¿Cómo debería ser la URL? Intenta a cambiarlo a `Nombre de la entrada` (penúltima opción)  en vez de usar la estructura personalizada `/%postname%/`

Comment: tanto "Nombre de la entrada" como "Estructura personalizada" poniendo el tag '/%postname%/' sigue fallando. A nivel de BBDD podria haber algun problema o se podria validar algo?

Comment: Usando `Nombre de la entrada` (penúltima opción) debería funcionar. A veces hay que limpiar la caché del navegador y para más seguridad probar en otro dispositivo. A veces los enlaces viejos podrían estar en caché y no funciona hasta que la caché no se limpia o se renueva. Lo malo es que si te pusiste a trastaer en otras partes como en el `.htaccess` o en la BD podrías haber cambiado alguna cosa que también impida que funcione adecuadamente. Generalmente desde el panel se pueden cambiar los permalinks sin modificar nada más.

Comment: El .htaccess lo he vaciado. Despues de ejecutar seleccionar "Nombre de la entrada" el .htaccess se ha rellenado automáticamente, pero sigue apareciendo el 404.